# Using Boostrap grid to change styling.

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to learn how to use the Bootstrap Grid, but having trouble figuring out how to style elements differently at different sizes. I want to change the position of the divs and the direction of the color gradients based on the size of the screen. I made 3 codepens to help visualize.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class='col-md-3 col-xs-12'>
        <div id="header">Header</div>
        <div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-9 col-xs-12'>
       <div id="main">Main</div> </div>

</div>
```

This is what it should look like on medium-large screens. 
https://codepen.io/tyl-er/pen/aWVpbN

```
.col-md-3 #header{
   background:linear-gradient(to right, yellow, green);
    height:25vh;
}
.col-md-3 #sidebar{
   background:linear-gradient(to right, yellow, green);
    height:75vh;
}
.col-md-9 #main {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, green , blue);
    height:100vh;
}
```

This is what it should look like on extra small screens. 
https://codepen.io/tyl-er/pen/bWYgdQ

```
.col-xs-12 #header{
   background:linear-gradient( red, yellow);
    height:25vh;
}
.col-xs-12 #sidebar{
   background:linear-gradient(yellow, green);
    height:25vh;
}
.col-xs-12 #main {
    background: linear-gradient(green , blue);
    height:50vh;
}
```

But when I try to combine the code it does not work.

Comment: Here's the third codepen
https://codepen.io/tyl-er/pen/RVjogo?editors=1100

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because the elements have the classes regardless of screen size and the styling applied last prevails. To actually apply styling based on screen size, you need to use media queries instead of relying on Bootstrap. In fact, Bootstrap internally uses media queries to change styling on the screen size classes that you are using.

Comment: Thanks. This might be a dumb question, but are media queries a feature of vanilla CSS? I've gone through a bunch of tutorials, but I haven't learned about them yet.

Comment: Yes. They *can* be a bit difficult to get a handle on.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use media queries as mentioned below

COdepen- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/OmOWGe?editors=1100

```
 #header{
   background:linear-gradient( red, yellow);
    height:25vh;
}
 #sidebar{
   background:linear-gradient(yellow, green);
    height:25vh;
}
 #main {
    background: linear-gradient(green , blue);
    height:50vh;
}


 /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

        #header{
   background:linear-gradient( red, yellow);
    height:25vh;
}
#sidebar{
   background:linear-gradient(yellow, green);
    height:25vh;
}
#main {
    background: linear-gradient(green , blue);
    height:50vh;
}


    }

    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

        #header{
   background:linear-gradient(to right, yellow, green);
    height:25vh;
}
#sidebar{
   background:linear-gradient(to right, yellow, green);
    height:75vh;
}
#main {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, green , blue);
    height:100vh;
}


    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm making my first professional website for someone else and it's also my first time making something for a mobile screen. What's the max-width for phone screens?

Comment: inspect your web page and you can see list of mobile devices you will find all the device screen size